# tensorflow-models/posenet in node js document.getElementById null

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, pose

I am new to js and nodejs. I have done a pose estimation using posenet
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet

I have tried the posenet inside the HTML code and everything is working as expected

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
    <!-- Load Posenet -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"></script>
 </head>

  <body>
    <img id='cat' src='/images/cat.jpg '/>
  </body>
  <!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
  <script>
    var flipHorizontal = false;

    var imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');

    posenet.load().then(function(net) {
      const pose = net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
        flipHorizontal: true
      });
      return pose;
    }).then(function(pose){
      console.log(pose);
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

After this, I have tried this using node js

```
const posenet = require('@tensorflow-models/posenet');

async function estimatePoseOnImage(imageElement) {
  // load the posenet model from a checkpoint
  const net = await posenet.load();

  const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
    flipHorizontal: false
  });
  return pose;
}

const imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');

const pose = estimatePoseOnImage(imageElement);

console.log(pose);
```

Here the problem is "imageElement" is always null. posnet needs a not null image element.

```
const imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');
   const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
    flipHorizontal: false
  });
```

1. Do I need to parse the HTML using puppeteer or htmlparser2?.
2. Do I need to use react or angular as the front end for this to work?

Thanks

Comment: But, Nodejs runs server-side. There is no DOM. `getElementById` makes no sense on a server. Not sure what you are trying to do here

Comment: Also `1. Do I need to parse the HTML using puppeteer` this question doesn't make sense either. Puppeteer is a web browser (actually it's like a robot that controls Chrome), it doesn't "parse" HTML code. It loads a web page and _outputs_ HTML code. `2. Do I need to use react or angular as the front end for this to work?` Absolutely not, why would you _need_ a front-end framework? It won't achieve anything you couldn't do with pure JS.

Comment: @JeremyThille My objective is to run posenet using nodejs. As mention in the question, the posenet needs an HTML element id to estimate pose. How do I achieve this in node js?

Comment: Well... you can't. As I mentioned, Node runs on a server, there's no DOM on a server, no `getElementById`

Comment: ok, Thanks @JeremyThille for the clarification